# Application TPS getting dropped while taking JFR

Tags: java, spring-boot, jfr

My Springboot application is designed for supporting 500 tps.
The application giving 500 TPS continuously, but when we take the JFR using below command, the application TPS is getting dropped to less than 100.

JFR command:

/opt/drutt/local/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/jcmd  JFR.start **settings=profile** duration=1m filename=/tmp/my_file_1.jfr

Is there any problem in JFR command?
Does JFR contribute in perfromance drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile setting could create significant overhead in certain applications, typically due to TLAB allocation event (or possibly exceptions), and is not recommended to have always on in production environments.

Remove settings=profile and the default configuration is used, which is safe in production (< 1% overhead)

Comment: by removing the settings=profile the TPS was not dropped. Thanks